# Sending email. Contact form with file attached

Tags: php, html

Hei.
I want the user's on my page to be able to upload a file and send me an email with all other inputs, including the uploaded file but i can't get it working. I am struggling with this for a quite a long time now and every single time i send a submision i get the message"Invalid file". I do get the email with all the data but the file is missing.
What am i doing wrong?

Here is the html form:

```
<form action="senden-bewerbung.php" id="contactform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="input">
                <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input">
                <label>Email adresse:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="input">
                <label>Nachname:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="surename" required>
            </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label>Telefonnummer:</label>
                <input type="tel" name="tel" required>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="input">
                <label>PLZ:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="plz" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input">
                <label>Stadt/Ort:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="stadt" required>
            </div>  
        </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
                <div class="input">
                    <label>Land:</label>
                        <select name="land" id="izbira">
                            <option value="Deutschland">Deutschland</option>
                            <option value="Österreich">Österreich</option>
                            <option value="Slowenien">Slowenien</option>
                            <option value="Croatien">Croatien</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                    <label>Geburtsdatum:</label>
                        <input type="date" name="geburtstag" required style="width:150px;">
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
                <div class="input">
                    <label>Ich bewerbe mich für:</label>
                        <select name="arbeit" id="izbira">
                            <option value="Krankenschwester">Krankenschwester</option>
                            <option value="Krankenpfleger">Krankenpfleger</option>
                            <option value="Kinderkrankenschwester">Kinderkrankenschwester</option>
                            <option value="Kinderkrankenpfleger">Kinderkrankenpfleger</option>
                            <option value="Altenpflegerin">Altenpflegerin</option>
                            <option value="Altenpfleger">Altenpfleger</option>
                            <option value="Hauswirtschaftsangestellte">Hauswirtschaftsangestellte</option>
                            <option value="Hauswirtschaftsangestellter">Hauswirtschaftsangestellter</option>
                            <option value="Pflegedienstleiterin">Pflegedienstleiterin</option>
                            <option value="Pflegedienstleiter">Pflegedienstleiter</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
                <div class="input">
                    <label>Lebenslauf hochladen (.pdf oder .doc/.docx .jpeg .png):</label>
                        <input type="file" name="lebenslauf" id="lebenslauf" size="16"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
                <div class="input"><label>Weiterbildung</label>
                    <input id="box1" type="checkbox" name="weiterbildung"/>
                        <label for="box1" name="Ja">Intensivfachweiterbildung</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <button type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">Senden</button>

        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is the php file:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$email_to = "info@domain.com";
$email_subject = "Kontakt";

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['surename']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['tel']) ||
    !isset($_POST['plz']) ||
    !isset($_POST['geburtstag']) ||
    !isset($_POST['stadt']) ||
    !isset($_POST['land']) ||
    !isset($_POST['arbeit']) ||
    !isset($_POST['weiterbildung'])) 

$first_name = $_POST['name']; // required
$sure_name = $_POST['surename']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$tel = $_POST['tel']; // required
$platz = $_POST['plz'];
$geburt = $_POST['geburtstag'];
$stadt = $_POST['stadt'];
$national = $_POST['land'];
$bewfur = $_POST['arbeit'];
$weiterb = $_POST['weiterbildung'];
$lebenslauf = $_FILES['lebenslauf']; // not required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'Die Email ist nicht gulting.<br />';
}
$email_message = "Daten uber den Bewerber:\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$allowedExts = array("doc", "docx", "gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "pdf", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["lebenslauf"]["name"]));  

if(

(
        ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif"  ) ||   
        ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" ) || 
        ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"  ) ||
        ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")      

)

&& 

        ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 400000)

&& 

        in_array($extension, $allowedExts)

) 
  if ($_FILES["uploads"]["error"] > 0) {
         echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
         }
       else {
          echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["lebenslauf"]["name"] . "<br />";
          echo "Type: " . $_FILES["lebenslauf"]["type"] . "<br />";
          echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["lebenslauf"]["size"] / 4024) . " Kb<br      />";
          echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["lebenslauf"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
             if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["lebenslauf"]["name"])) {
                echo $_FILES["lebenslauf"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
       }
          else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["lebenslauf"]["tmp_name"],
             "upload/" . $_FILES["lebenslauf"]["name"]);
             echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["lebenslauf"]["name"];
          }
    }
    else {
       echo "Invalid file";
    }

$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Nachname: ".clean_string($sure_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telefonnummer: ".clean_string($tel)."\n";
$email_message .= "Platz: ".clean_string($platz)."\n";
$email_message .= "Geburtsdatumm: ".clean_string($geburt)."\n";
$email_message .= "Stadt: ".clean_string($stadt)."\n";
$email_message .= "Land: ".clean_string($national)."\n";
$email_message .= "Arbeit: ".clean_string($bewfur)."\n";
$email_message .= "Weiterbildung: ".clean_string($weiterb)."\n";
$email_message .= "Lebenslauf: ".clean_string($lebenslauf)."\n";



$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
}
?>
```

Comment: `print_r($_FILES)` should tell you all you need to know

Comment: Your file input name is `uploads` and not `lebenslauf`.

Comment: It looks like in the form you have the file field called uploads, but in your script you try to access $_FILES['lebenslauf']. That might be your issue.

Comment: No, in the html file it is `lebenslauf` i just posted the wrong file here.